# Returning two values of two different types in a C++ function

Tags: c++, function, return

I'm writing a program that performs a simple rotation (think like rot13) on a string taken from user input. My problem is that I want to change each character in the string's ASCII value by a different amount each time - and so I'm using a for loop to go through the string, and calling a function that generates a random number each time. However, I want to be able to return this number so that I can "unscramble" the string at a later date. I also need to return the string though, obviously.

Here's my code:

```
int ranFunction()
{

    int number = rand() % 31;
    return number;

}

string rotFunction(string words)
{
    int upper_A = 65;
    int lower_z = 122;
    int rand_int = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++)
    {
        rand_int = ranFunction();

        if (words[i] >= upper_A && words[i] <= lower_z) {

            words[i] -= rand_int;


        }

    }
    return words; 
}
```

I'm hoping to get rotFunction to return words AND an integer based on whatever rand_int happens to be each time.

Just a note: the numbers I'm using RE: ascii values etc are totally arbitrary right now, just there for testing.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/487/returning-several-values-from-a-function#t=201701261136058675108) may be of your interest

Comment: Why not return a struct.

Comment: @Arco3  For starters should this statement  rand_int = ranFunction(); be outside the loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way would be to return a `struct` or `class` type.

```
 struct rotReturn
 {
      int ran;
      std::string str;
 };

 rotReturn rotFunction(std::string words)
 {
     // what you have, except for the return
     rotReturn retval
     retval.ran = rand_int;
     retval.str = words;
     return retval;
 }
```

Obviously, it is possible to optimise and use the structure to be returned within the function, rather than using separate variables for intermediate results.

Alternatives include returning an `std::pair<int, std::string>` or (for more values to be bundled), a `std::tuple`.    Both of these are specialised `struct` or `class` types.

It is also possible to pass such types to functions, by reference or pointer (address), so the caller can pass an object which the function stores data into.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 7):

To return two different types use `std::pair`

```
std::pair<T1,T2> foo(){
    return std::make_pair(v1,v2);
}
```

Example:

```
std::pair<int,float> foo(){
    return std::make_pair(5,0.5f);
}
```

---

To return **more** than two different types use **`std::tuple`**:

```
std::tuple<T1,T2,...,Tn> foo(){
    return std::make_tuple(v1,v2,...,vn);
}
```

Example:

```
std::tuple<int,float,std::string> foo(){
    return std::make_tuple(5,0.5f,"sss");
}
```

Comment: Tip) Since C++17 ([CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)), we can return just `std::tuple(5,0.5f,"sss")` instead of `make_tuple`. (Before C++17 it should be explicitly `std::tuple<int,float,std::string>(5,0.5f,"sss")`, so just using `make_tuple` would be simpler). Also, since C++14 we can use `auto` for the return type, so this would be enough: `auto foo() {return std::tuple(5, 0.5f, "sss")}`.